# C# binary array to decimal?

Tags: c#, sql

In SQL, the following works `cast([comlum] as Decimal(18,4))`

How can I do the same conversion (from the binary data) in C#?

---

the data type of varbinary in SQL C# loading to byte[] so, I want to byte[] convert to decimal or double?

Sql query: `select cast([column_A] as decimal(18,4), [column_A] from table`

result: 191128.0000      0x1204000180D1EB71

I hope to get value as `191128.0000` in C#

---

Because, I use entity framework 
so, have this question

Comment: I updated my answer to take your update into account.

Answer (score 4):

To cast a byte array to a C# decimal and vice versa you might use this piece of code:

```
decimal d = 12.3456789m;

// decimal to byte[]
byte[] bytes = new byte[16];
Buffer.BlockCopy(decimal.GetBits(d), 0, bytes, 0, 16);

// byte[] to decimal
int[] bits = new int[4];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, bits, 0, 16);
Console.WriteLine(new decimal(bits));  // 12.3456789
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, what does the binary array contain? Is it an existing `decimal` represented as a `byte[]`? Unlike things like `float` / `double`, there is no common/shared understanding of `decimal` as `byte[]`.

But if it **is** a .NET `decimal` you could use the overload of `new decimal(int[])` - but you'll need to pack the bytes into ints first; which means you need to know the endianness...

Or is the array actually a `double`? In which case, `BitConverter` should help.

---

Having seen the update to the question, I suspect that you are going to *have* to cast this data (in TSQL) *before* it comes out of SQL Server, or dig out the implementation-specific encoding used to pack the data in SQL Server (which would be brittle, and IMO probably shouldn't leave the server). There is a `SqlDecimal` type, but this *also* doesn't accept a `byte[]`.